# Set logging level in glog package

Tags: go, logging, error-logging, glog

How can I set logging level for golang [glog](https://github.com/golang/glog) package to ERROR.

example.go:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/golang/glog"
    "flag"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    glog.Info("Info level")
    glog.Error("Error level")
    glog.Flush()
}
```

```
$ go run example.go -logtostderr=true -stderrthreshold=ERROR
I1214 15:46:00.743002   13429 example.go:10] Info level
E1214 15:46:00.743211   13429 example.go:11] Error level
```

In the above example I have set the `stderrthreshold` flag to ERROR but am still getting INFO level logs. I want only ERROR level logs.

Comment: glog's level work on the V, not on the Info, Warning, Error stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, glog will write

- all log messages to log files (they are created in `/tmp` by default);
- log messages with a severity of `stderrthreshold` or above to stderr.

By using the `-logtostderr=true` flag this behaviour is changed:

> Logs are written to standard error instead of to files.

- no log messages are written to log files;
- all log messages are written to stderr.

The `stderrthreshold` presumably has no effect when `-logtostderr=true` is used. And in your invocation it didn't have an effect anyway, because the default threshold is already `ERROR`.

To summarize, by just running `go run example.go` without any command line arguments, only log messages with severity `ERROR` or above are written to stderr, as you desired.